# NotRegistered Error Returned Without RegistrationID

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing out the responses FCM is sending me and I've encountered a problem. FCM will return an error for devices it couldn't send a notification to - but it doesn't say what the registration ID is for the failed push.

```
public async static void SendPushNotification(string title, string strMessage, string clickLocation, List<string> registrationIDs) {
        ResponseContent resp;
        using (var sender = new Sender(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FCMKey")))
        {
            var json = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"json message\",\"body\":\"works like a charm!\"},\"registration_ids\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registrationIDs) + "}";
            resp = await sender.SendAsync(json);
        }
        HandleFCMResponse(resp);
    }

    private static void HandleFCMResponse(ResponseContent response) {
        if (response.MessageResponse.Failure > 0)
        {
            foreach (Result r in response.MessageResponse.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.RegistrationId);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("resp");
    }
```

Empty registration id:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the result as JSONString, you would see that the result has an array for the errors/responses. The array corresponds to the order of registration tokens specified in your `registration_ids` parameter.

In your screenshot, it shows 2 results, which is presuming also the count of registration tokens in `registration_ids`. Both are returning the `NotRegistered` error. Which means token[0] and token[1] in your list are both invalid tokens.

Possibly similar post: [firebase - How to know which registration_id is bad/expired/deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41101678/4625829)

Comment: So the only way to determine the bad registration id's is by the order they were submitted? Seems strange...

Comment: @Tomcelic Yup. It's just the expected behavior.